# How to correctly submit AJAX to DB

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, jeditable

AIM: To allow the use to update the table on the client side and then update the DB once they press enter with the new changes and have the new changes show on the client side.

STATUS: Currently I am able to display the table, edit the table using jeditable and `POST` the values via `id` and `value` variable to my server side out.jsp page, which then uses `request.getParamater` to receive the var and display back to the client side. I am also using JDBC with SQLITE to dynamically generate these tables and would like to use the same process to insert or replace the new values back.

QUESTION: How can pass more information about the row/column information in order to correctly  update the DB with these new values ?

QUESTION 2: IS there a way to pass the entire row? If so I could just do a simple insert or replace for all the values back into the table.

Current Code:

JSP Client Side: client.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/jedit.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<title>Jeditable Test</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.edit').editable('out.jsp', {
        indicator : 'Saving...',
        tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
    });
});


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <table id="demotable1"
            style="border: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 50px auto;">
            <thead style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">
                <tr>
                    <th filter-type='ddl' style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">ONE</th>
                    <th filter-type='ddl' style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">TWO</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class='edit' in="ONE" style='border: 1px solid #ccc;'>Value 1</td>
                    <td class='edit' id="TWO" style='border: 1px solid #ccc;'>Value 2</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class='edit' id="ONE" style='border: 1px solid #ccc;'>Value 3</td>
                    <td class='edit' id="TWO" style='border: 1px solid #ccc;'>Value 4</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Table image:

[image: Editable Table]

JSP - out.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

                <% 
                String id = request.getParameter("id");
                String value = request.getParameter("value");

                %>
</head>
<body>
<%=id%>
<%=value%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and thought that I should post if anyone is interested.

JQUERY:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Init DataTables */
    var oTable = $('#resource-table').dataTable();

    /* Apply the jEditable handlers to the table */
    $('td', oTable.fnGetNodes()).editable( 'out.jsp', {
        "callback": function( sValue, y ) {
            var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
            oTable.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1] );
        },
        "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
            return {
                "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
                "id": this.getAttribute('id'),
                "colName": this.getAttribute('col'),
                "column": oTable.fnGetPosition( this )[2]
            };
        },
        "height": "14px"
    } );
} );   

</script>
```

The above passed the parameters to the JSP Page, which GET's the paramters.

```
String colName = request.getParameter("colName");
String value = request.getParameter("value");
String row = request.getParameter("row_id");
String column = request.getParameter("column");
```

The row was off by 1 as it used the TR bar as a row. So used the below to sort that out.

```
int rowId = Integer.parseInt(row);
        rowId += 1;
```

Then used a JDBC connection via JSP scriptlet(Not MVC.. I know)

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/db.sqlite");
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        add_time = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE table SET "+colName+" ='"+value+"' WHERE rowid = "+rowId+";");
        add_time.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly `jedittable` submits to the server but if the ids used are `id` and `value` then for a table with multiple rows you might have more than one value for the same parameter name, so i would use [getParameterValues](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29) to retrieve them all as `String[]`. both arrays for `id` and `value` should have the same length.

To be able to identify each row you'll have to have some sort of unique id for each record/row witch is saved in the database.

such an id can be generated for example using [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)

```
String uid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

witch produces something like

```
76c824f7-3016-4a15-a10f-a60435dc966f
```

while generating the HTML upon a GET request you'll have to generate a name for each cell using the uid in the form `<uuid>_<column_name>`, for example for the record with the uid `76c824f7-3016-4a15-a10f-a60435dc966f` and the columnns `ONE` and `TWO`

```
<td name="76c824f7-3016-4a15-a10f-a60435dc966f_ONE" ...>value 1</td>
<td name="76c824f7-3016-4a15-a10f-a60435dc966f_TWO" ...>value 2</td>
```

and for the record with the uid `1a8c2aad-a438-4263-972b-30a839421e6d`

```
<td name="1a8c2aad-a438-4263-972b-30a839421e6d_ONE" ...>value 3</td>
<td name="1a8c2aad-a438-4263-972b-30a839421e6d_TWO" ...>value 4</td>
```

and so on.

After a post you'll have to load all records, generate the names and use [getParameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) to retrieve each column value and update it.

You'll have to consider new record witch you'll have to insert into the database.

If you want to send a entire row as a single parameter to the server you have to process it using javascript on the browser. you can for example generate something like

```
'76c824f7-3016-4a15-a10f-a60435dc966f=value 1,value 2'
'1a8c2aad-a438-4263-972b-30a839421e6d=value 3,value 4'
```

the parameter name would be the uid. after splitting the comma separated values you can update each column of the corresponding record.

Comment: Thanks, Thats what I had in mind, as I need three references to target the right row/column. I was hoping that there was more var POST'ed from jeditable like row_id or column name by default. Do you have any experience with jeditable?

Comment: unfortunately not :/ ... this how how my answer starts ;-)

Comment: you could use `getParameterMap` to see all the data submitted and maybe (hopefully) you'll recognize something. javadoc -> http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following concepts :

More Standard way : Exchange data using JSON Object

1. JSON Objects to construct to send data to AJAX
2. jQuery AJAX for call to your application server
3. Use JSON library to convert the JSON String into Java Object and then do the transaction.

1) Define your data-structure of JSON Object :

Java Class :

```
 class OneDBRow {
      String col1Value;
      String col2Value;
  }
```

Corresponding JSON Array of Objects

```
  {
      {type:"OneDBRow", col1Value: "hello", col2Value: "Value 2"},
      {type:"OneDBRow", col1Value: "Value 3", col2Value: "Value 4"}
  }
```

2) Construct the JSON Object using javascript side (use JQuery)

3) Populate the Object using jQuery Selector

4) Send the object as part of data- you have to construct the object using JSON library

I dont know the exact syntaxes to create the Array of Objects , you might have to research for yourself.